# virtual scroll on Angular 7 is not visible - the height is zero by default

Tags: angular, angular7, virtualscroll

**Scenario:**

- Tried a basic virtual scroll test reading this [blog post](https://blog.angular.io/version-7-of-angular-cli-prompts-virtual-scroll-drag-and-drop-and-more-c594e22e7b8c)
- the array had lots of items
- there was no error
- the list loaded in a virtual scroll but the height of it was 0 by default

**quick fix was** to

- set the height for cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport to 500px or  set the
  height for class 'example-viewport' in app.component.css

**Question**:
what is the proper way to overcome this zero height?

sample at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efdcyc

Comment: With a `height: 100%;` it will get the parents height, you can handle the parents size as any other div in your page.

Comment: @ibenjelloun, wouldn't work... you can try here https://angular-efdcyc.stackblitz.io/ ... but am i missing some dependency which should take care of it?

Comment: Imho the way to style the `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` element is totally arbitrary and a hit or miss. The `itemSize` property makes no sense at all, so you have to play with styles and the property until you get it about right. The documentation and the design of the component is a joke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This CSS works for me (no fixed height required):

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport class="viewport">  
   .......
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

.viewport { 
   display: contents;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before you paste this in even more locations, please take the time to read [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).

Answer (score 12):

- use **min-height** of 100% for the viewport and verify
- make sure, the height set on the viewport with 'itemSize' matches the height of 
  the item in css
- if you are using an Observable, make sure to resolve it with *ngIf and the async pipe. Important: 
  the html element is an **ng-container**, because it may not 
  be rendered for the min-width to work!

  ```
    .list {
       min-height: 100%;
    }

    .item {
       height: 100px;
    }
  ```

When using an Observable as a source

```
<ng-container *ngIf="obs$ | async; let data">
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="100" class="list">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, item height of 100px is arbitary... (2nd bullet) height of the item can change during responsiveness to screen size so we can't get the exact match;

Answer (score 6):

Add necessary CSS styles to provide the height of the element

```
.example-viewport {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.example-item {
  height: 50px;
}
```

You can see the full content of the example you have mentioned here. https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

They also used custom CSS to style their elements.

[Updated Slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcl59d?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: height of 50px or 500px is not exact... it should be tied to the itemSize which we define in <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>... but you're right that the example also gave a fixed number for the height !!

Comment: I saw that elements exist but screen was completely white. Until I saw your solution.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From these answers, I like the one with `display: contents;` most because it has no % or px.

This also worked for me:

```
cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport { 
    contain: none;
}
```