# cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport with variable item heights

Tags: angular, angular7, virtualscroll

I would like to use `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` in a TimeLine view with items of different heights.

So setting `itemSize="x"` which, according to the documentation refers to *The size of the items in the list (in pixels)*, is unpractical.

`autosize` is not yet available.

Is it possible at all to use virtual/endless scrolling with `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` vith variable item sizes?

**Update**

I was looking for alternative virtual/endless scrolling solutions and, I hardly can believe, it seems there is *no* solution which works with dynamic row height, even with https://github.com/rintoj/ngx-virtual-scroller it's not recommended.

**Update 2, July 2019**

Since meanwhile there is still no solution, I believe the "good enough" way to work around this would be to load a fixed number of items, and add a button to load more items at the bottom of the list, like in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-mat-load-more

Comment: It is under development. see https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10113

Comment: Please have a look here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-virtual-scroll-simple-autosize

Answer (score 11):

**autosize** works for me.

Try to install:

```
"@angular/cdk": "6.2.0",
"@angular/cdk-experimental": "6.2.0"
```

and then import **ScrollingModule** into your module:

```
import {ScrollingModule} from "@angular/cdk-experimental";

imports: [ScrollingModule]
```

then you can use **autosize** property like below:

```
 <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport autosize style="height: 100%">
```

Comment: I think you need both the stable and experimental module imported:

import { ScrollingModule as ExperimentalScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk-experimental/scrolling';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

imports: [ScrollingModule, ExperimentalScrollingModule]

Comment: "@angular/cdk": "12.2.8",
"@angular/cdk-experimental": "12.2.8"

If i have set only autosize, i get an error
Error: cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport requires the "itemSize" property to be set.

Comment: @Juri did you find the solution?

Comment: @Maurice i guess somithing with my module configuration is wrong, adden both modules in shared module and now it seems to work. Thx for asking

Comment: I have this error: "Multiple components match node with tagname cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport." I use @angular/cdk: "12.2.13, @angular/cdk-experimental: 6.4.7. Should I match both the version?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it si working for me ... The strange thing is that in "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.0" we still do not have this behaviour

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found the solution:
In my case, I recently use @angular/cdk version 12.2.13 and so you should install too @angular/cdk-experimental with version 12.2.13 (the same version).

Go to app.module.ts:
add this line:

```
import { ScrollingModule as ExperimentalScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk-experimental/scrolling';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
```

and in imports:

```
[ScrollingModule,
    ExperimentalScrollingModule]
```

Then do this:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
          autosize
          style="height: 100%"
          class="container"
        >
your content
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Until this feature is offered in the CDK I got around it by listening to the onscroll event of the native element then respond when the scroll offset to the bottom is 0

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport, { static: false })
public virtualScrollViewport?: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

...

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.virtualScrollViewport.elementRef.nativeElement.onscroll = (e) => { this.onScroll(e) };
}

onScroll(e) {
  var scrollOffset = this.virtualScrollViewport.measureScrollOffset("bottom");

  if (scrollOffset == 0) {
    this.fetchMoreData();
  }
}
```

Comment: May I ask how this solves the item height problem? The point of the virtual scroll was to render the items only as they are shown in the viewport, and for that reason to be able to calculate that requires a fixed item height. Your solution seems to be about loading the next items, not solving the variable height issue.

Comment: One issue with dynamic heights, or in my case expandable rows, is that scrolling will sometimes load items prematurely or not at all because the trigger points are inconsistent. This work around will provide a more reliable experience for when to load the next batch of items so that the user is never stuck at the bottom of the scrollable area. However, it does not address the issue of only rendering visible items.

Answer (score 0):

itemSize="x" doesn't help set the height... you'd have to use CSS to assign an arbitary height yourself.

- **ref:** [virtual scroll on Angular 7 - the height is zero by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945836/virtual-scroll-on-angular-7-the-height-is-zero-by-default)

coming to your question, variable item sizes should not be a problem with the virtual scroll... you can change the array [in this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efdcyc) to see the possibility & results very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS works for me. No fixed height required:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport class="viewport">  
   .......
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>

.viewport { 
   display: contents;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before you paste this in even more locations, please take the time to read [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me is the example of splaktar at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport-with-dynamic-itemsize?file=app%2Fcdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.html)

Template:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="itemSize" class="example- 
viewport">
<div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items"
   [style.height]="itemSize + 'px'">{{item}}</div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
<br>
<div>
<label for="height">Item Size:</label>
<input id="height" type="number" [(ngModel)]="itemSize">
</div>
```

component:

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example',
styleUrls: ['cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.css'],
templateUrl: 'cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.html',
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class CdkVirtualScrollOverviewExample {
items = Array.from({length: 100000}).map((_, i) => `Item #${i}`);
itemSize = 80;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to set cdkvirtualscrollviewport height dynamically with [ngStyle]

```
          <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
        itemSize="parent?.children.length"
        [ngStyle]="{'height.px': parent?.children.length<10? parent?.children.length*42 :250 }"
      >
```

Comment: could you explai a bit more? What is `parent?` exactly? and `height.px` ?