# CdkVirtualScrollViewport is already attached (ERROR)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cdk

I´m working in a project where i need to display more 1000 records and was think in use virtual scroll from the angular material CDK but for some reason i get this error: `Error: CdkVirtualScrollViewport is already attached.`.

**Template**

```
<div class="news-feeds-wrapper">
  <div class="news-feeds-icon" *ngIf="configService.config.showNewsFeeds" (click)="toggleNewsFeeds()">
    <span *ngIf="platform.EDGE || platform.TRIDENT" class="icon-hype-notification_important"></span>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!platform.EDGE && !platform.TRIDENT">notification_important</mat-icon>
  </div>
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50">
    <div class="news-feeds-list" [ngClass]="{'open': newsFeedOpen}">
      <div *cdkVirtualFor="let group of newsFeeds">
        <div class="time" *ngIf="group.values.length > 0">{{group.type}}</div>
        <div class="news-feed" *cdkVirtualFor="let item of group.values | async">
          <div class="header">
            <i [ngSwitch]="item.action_type">
              <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="'Task Assignment'">swap_horiz</mat-icon>
              <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="'User Mention'">chat</mat-icon>
              <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="'Task Deleted'">no_sim</mat-icon>
            </i>
            <span>{{item.action_type}}</span>
            <mat-icon class="deleted-news-feed" (click)="deletedNewsFeeds(group.values, item)">clear</mat-icon>
          </div>
          <div class="news-feed-content">
            <div class="info-content">
              <p class="project">{{item.project}}</p>
              <p class="taskboard">{{item.task_board}}</p>
              <p class="board-item">{{item.task_board_item}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="avatar">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'news-feeds',
  templateUrl: '../templates/news-feed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../assets/scss/news-feeds.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class NewsFeedsComponent implements OnInit {
  public newsFeedOpen = false;
  public newsFeeds: Array<any> = [];

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  closeNewsFeeds(event) {
    if (this.newsFeedOpen && event.target.localName != 'mat-icon') {
      this.newsFeedOpen = false;
    }
  }

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public configService: HypeConfigService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef, private log: LoggingService, private backlogService: BacklogTaskService) {
    //
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //
  }

  toggleNewsFeeds() {
    this.backlogService.getNewsFeeds().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.newsFeedOpen = !this.newsFeedOpen;
        this.newsFeeds = response;
        this.cd.markForCheck();
      },
      (error) => {
        this.log.error(`Error loading the news feeds: ${error}`);
      }
    );
  }

  deletedNewsFeeds(group: Array<any>, newsFeed: any) {
    const index = group.findIndex((i) => i.id === newsFeed.id);
    group.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

so for some reason is telling me that CdkVirtualScrollViewport is attached already but i not using in any other place on my application. [stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzscmq)

Comment: a minimal stackblitz will make the cause more clearer to see and share

Comment: Here a small
[stackblitz ]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzscmq

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to the fact that you used *cdkVirtualFor twice, one inside the other... 
To resolve, I made 2 changes;

1. **app.component.html**: used *ngFor instead of *cdkVirtualFor, so

   - `<div class="news-feed" *ngFor="let item of group.values">` instead of
   - `<div class="news-feed" *cdkVirtualFor="let item of group.values">`
2. **app.component.css**: Added `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport { height:400px; }` because the [height is zero by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945836/virtual-scroll-on-angular-7-the-height-is-zero-by-default)

**HTML changes & CSS addition in the code snippet below**

```css
cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-feeds-wrapper">
  <div class="news-feeds-list open">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" class="example-viewport">
      <div *cdkVirtualFor="let group of newsfeeds">
        <div class="time">{{group.type}}</div>
        <div class="news-feed" *ngFor="let item of group.values">
          <div class="header">
            <span>{{item.action_type}}</span>
            <mat-icon class="deleted-news-feed">clear</mat-icon>
          </div>
          <div class="news-feed-content">
            <div class="info-content">
              <p class="project">{{item.project}}</p>
              <p class="taskboard">{{item.task_board}}</p>
              <p class="board-item">{{item.task_board_item}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="avatar">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you are right, if this is the case i think there is no way to put the `*cdkVirtualFor` in the second iteration instead of the first one...

Comment: Thanks for the upVote, You can test this in your actual code also... I'd appreciate if you mark the answer as accepted also.